# Twilio Rest API - Modify live call and dial

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I need to make an outbound call to an agent and connect a customer. After agent speaks to the customer, the customer should be connected to another person.

Can I use rest API to dial the third person by modifying the live call with a url? Need to complete the agent's call. Dial and connect the third person with the customer.

Here is the documentation.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This sounds like it could be a warm transfer scenario, where one person transfers a caller to another.

Here is a [tutorial on how to accomplish a warm transfer with Twilio and PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/warm-transfer/php/laravel). Take a look through there and let me know if it helps.